# Moving files into sub folders based by average filesize

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ffmpeg

I need the help of you programming savants in creating a batch script or powershell script that will move and divide a group of files from one directory into 4 subdirectories based on an average total filesize. After the sort, the sub-directories should be roughly equal in terms of folder size.

Why do I need this?

I have 4 computers that I would like to utilize for encoding via FFMPEG and it would be helpful for a script to divide a folder into 4 parts (sub-directories) based on a total average size.

So lets say there are an assortment of movie files with varying different file sizes totaling to 100 GB, the script would divy the movie files and move them into 4 sub folders; each folder having around 25 GB. Doing this will allow the 4 machines to encode the sum of the data equally and efficiently.

After all that encoding I'll have 2 files, XYZ.(original Extension) and XYZ.264, A script that could compare the 2 files and delete the larger file would be extremely helpful and cut down on manual inspection.

Thank you, I hope this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
:: number of subdirectories
SET /a parts=4
:: make subdirs and initialise totalsizes
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%parts%) DO MD "%destdir%\sub%%a" 2>nul&SET /a $%%a=0
:: directory of sourcefiles, sort in reverse-size order
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-s * '
 ) DO (
 REM find smallest subdir by size-transferred-in
 SET /a smallest=2000000000
 FOR /L %%p IN (1,1,%parts%) DO IF !$%%p! lss !smallest! SET /a smallest=!$%%p!&SET part=%%p
 REM transfer the file and count the size
 ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\sub!part!"
 REM divide by 100 as actual filelength possibly gt 2**31
 SET "size=%%~za"
 IF "!size:~0,-2!" equ "" (SET /a $!part!+=1) ELSE (SET /a $!part!=!size:~0,-2! + $!part!)
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

I believe the remarks should explain the method. The principle is to record the length-transferred to each subdirectory and select the least-filled as the destination for the file (processed in reverse-size order)

Since batch has a limit of 2^31, I chose to roughly divide the filesize by 100 by lopping of the last 2 digits. For files <100 bytes, I arbitrarily recorded that as 100 bytes.

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "spaces=                             "
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad "%destdir%\*"'
  ) DO (
 PUSHD "%destdir%\%%a"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "*.xyz" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
   IF EXIST "%%f.264" (
    FOR %%k IN ("%%f.264") DO (
     SET "sizexyz=%spaces%%%~zf"
     SET "size264=%spaces%%%~zk"
     IF "!sizexyz:~-15!" gtr "!size264:~-15!" (ECHO(DEL /F /Q "%%f") ELSE (ECHO(DEL /F /Q "%%f.264")
    )
   )
  )
 popd
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This second batch scans the directorynames into `%%a` then switches teporarily to the detination directory `%destfile\%%a`.

Once there, we look for `.xyz` files and for each one found, find the corresponding `.xyz.264` file.

If that exists, then we find the sizes of the files (`%%~zk` or `%%~zf`) and append that to a long string of spaces. By comparing the last 15 characters of the result as a string, we can determine which is longer.

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

If the `.264` file is `filename.264` instead of `filename.xyz.264` then replace **each** `"%%f.264"` with `"%%~nf.264"` (the `~n` selects the name-part only).

---

To manually enter a source directoryname, use

```
 SET /p "sourcedir=Source directory "
```

To accept the source directoryname as a parameter, use

```
 SET "sourcedir=%%~1"
```

To process all files, except `.h264` files, change

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "*.xyz" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (
```

to

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "*.*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO if /i "%%~xf" neq ".h264" (
```

where `*.*` means "all files" and the extra `if` statement checks whether the extension to the filename `%%f` (`%%~xf`) is not equal to (`neq`) `.h264` and the `/i` directs "regardless of case (case-**I**nsensitive)"

Comment: Wow, that's amazing, every sub directory is pretty much split perfectly in the test I did!

Comment: Is there anyway to compare 2 files that have the exact same filename but different extensions, and automatically delete the larger one?  For example if I have a 500mb 1.mp4 and a 200mb 1.h264  a script would delete the larger file?

Comment: Thanks so much for your script, it worked beautifully

Comment: Is it possibe to make this script work if I drop it in a directory with the filenames? Instead of assigning the directory? And also sometimes the file extensions are different, such as wmv, mp4, ect.. so instead of checking for *.xyz, can it instead check against all files that don't have the .h264 extension? I've been studying your script for the last 2 hours trying to edit it to work, but I'm at a lost.

Answer (score 1):

This might seem like a simple request, but [exact partitioning is actually a really hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

The easiest way to approximate a somewhat fair partitioning is simply to sort all files (from biggest to smallest) and then distribute them one-by-one into *n* groups (a bit like if you were giving out cards for a card game):

```
# Define number of subgroups/partitions
$n = 4

# Create your destination folders:
$TargetFolders = 1..$n |ForEach-Object {
    mkdir "C:\path\to\movies\sub$_"
}

# Find the movie files sort by length, descending
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\movies" -Recurse |Where-Object {'.mp4','.mpg','.xyz' -contains $_.Extension} |Sort-Object Length -Descending

for($i = 0; $i -lt $Files.Count; $i++)
{
    # Move files into sub folders, using module $n to "rotate" target folder
    Move-Item $Files[$i].FullName -Destination $TargetFolders[$i % $n] 
}
```

---

If you have multiple file types that you want to include, use a `Where-Object` filter instead of the `Filter` parameter with `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\movies" -File -Recurse |Where-Object {'.mp4','.mpg','.xyz' -contains $_.Extension} |Sort-Object Length -Descending
```

Comment: Just a note, `% $n` is zero based (for $n=4 you get 0,1,2,3 repeating), but your folders are 1 based... so you're trying to put files into sub0, sub1, sub2, and sub3, but only 3 of those will exist.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Notice I use `$i % $n` as an index accessor value, and since array indexing is *also* zero-based, that problem solves itself no matter what I named the folders :)

Comment: Well, I derped pretty hard there. Thanks, you are quite right! Sorry about that.

Comment: @darkshaed You'll have to be a little more specific than "the directory is a little weird" if you want help troubleshooting :)

Comment: Thanks Mathias, the script certainly does divide files into their own directory, the directory structure is a little weird though., I'm getting Sub1\Sub1, Sub2\Sub2, so it creates 4 folders, but 2 are nested into each other with the files being divided into each folder. Is this working as intended?

Comment: No that shouldn't be the case. What did you change the path to in the line that starts with `mkdir`?

Comment: for the -Filter *.xyz, how do I add more than one file type? do I do *.mp4 *.mov ect..?

Comment: @darkshaed my bad, I forget the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`, so two of the folders get moved as well, update the example script in the answer

Comment: I'm getting an error with "get-childitem: a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'. At C:\test\test.ps1:10 char:45

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: v1.0, do I need to upgrade?

Comment: o_O Yes, definitely! But it sounds like you need to upgrade your operating system first

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen he may just be confused because of the v1.0 path to the executable. Almost no one has 1.0.

Comment: Does 2.0 come prepackaged with a certain type of windows? I have both windows 7 & 8 machines, I checked the Win 8 machine and it's still only 1.0 =(

Comment: Win7 ships with PowerShell 2.0, Win8 ships with PowerShell 3.0 (don't worry about the `v1.0` in the folder name). Version 2.0 won't recognize the `-File` parameter to `Get-ChildItem`, 3.0 will

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

nbr_of_dirs=4

# Go to directory if specified, otherwise execute in current directory
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    cd $1
fi

# Create output directories and store them in an array
for i in $(seq 1 $nbr_of_dirs); do
    dir=dir_$i
    mkdir $dir
    dirs[i]=$dir
done

# For every non-directory, in decreasing size:
# find out the current smallest directory and move the file there
ls -pS | grep -v / | while read line; do
    smallest_dir=$(du -S ${dirs[@]} | sort -n | head -1 | cut -f2)
    mv "$line" $smallest_dir
done
```

Remember to keep the script file in a different directory when executing this. The script iterates over every file, so if the script was in the directory too it would be moved to one of the sub-directories.

Comment: Where in the script do I input the path of where the directory of files are?

Comment: I would run the script from the directory where the files are. Alternatively, you might add a line like `cd $1` at the top to take you to a directory specified as the first input argument. Which then executes the rest of the code there.

Comment: Hmm, I can't get it to do anything, thank you for your help anyways

Comment: Hmm, my bad I guess. I misread the question and thought you were asking for a "batch script or _shell_", not powershell. So this code is only going run in a Unix environment or on an emulator. I verified just now that it works in Git Bash on Windows 7, so that's an option if you're interested.