# In Powershell with a large number of files can you send 2GB at a time to zip files rather than splitting a zip?

Tags: powershell, zip

I have hundreds of thousands of files in about 30 folders with a total size of about 1.9TB. I have been asked to split these files into zip files of 2GB in size.

Has anyone heard of a way using Powershell and a zip program like winrar or 7zip to do this? I have tried looking within the applications themselves but they just want to split a large archive into multiple files not create individual zips from a large number of files.

I assume that the best way may be to get 2GB of files at a time and move them to a folder so that I end up with something like 950 folders. Then create a zip from each folder. I just don't know how to do that though.

Comment: I'd honestly be inclined to ask why if I was asked to do this... If the goal is to free up space but these files can't be deleted/have to be archived I'd consider getting one or more USB-drives for them instead. But then again,  I have no idea how important these files are considered to be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815633/dotnetzip-calculate-final-zip-size-before-calling-savestream-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any program that would take care of grouping the files into suitable groups then zipping them, but in terms of creating the ZIPs themselves, PowerShell has a `Compress-Archive` cmdlet you could use.

In terms of the grouping, you are probably going to have a difficult time optimising this as your task seems very like the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem), which is known to be computationally hard.

I don't know of any algorithm implementations in PowerShell, but here are some in C++ that you can possibly convert:

[Bin Packing Problem (Minimize number of used Bins)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bin-packing-problem-minimize-number-of-used-bins/)

You could, of course, try some possibilities of your own.  For example, a naïve attempt might be:

1. Sort all the files by size in descending order
2. Take the largest file (assumed to be < 2GB) and add to a ZIP
3. Take the smallest file and if adding won't tip the ZIP file over 2GB, add it
4. Repeat Step 3 with the next smallest file until no more can be added
5. Repeat Steps 2-4, until all files are archived

This should work, but is probably horribly inefficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. I will look into them. To clarify some things. The files are .eml files and they are to be uploaded to a cloud archive system. Unfortunately the provider required only 2GB zip files containing the eml files to be uploaded. I am not trying to get the zip file at 2GB more trying to get 2GB of eml files as I understand calculating total compressed size would be difficult. This way would also most likely end up with more files but if they are going to be this crazy they can deal with the larger number of files on their end.

Comment: This person has done exactly what I need without the zipping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214095/moving-files-into-sub-folders-based-by-average-filesize

Comment: I have used the following powershell script to zip the files within each subfolder `#Compress all the files based on folder structure

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TestDivide\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
 $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
 $directoryName = $_.Name
 & "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip $directoryFullName\*
}


#Move the zip files to a specific directory

Get-childitem -path "C:\TestDivide" -Recurse -Filter "*.zip" | move-item -destination c:\Testdivide`

Answer (score 0):

So the code to divide the files mentioned in my comment ended up looking like this

```
# Define number of subgroups/partitions
$n = 4

# Create your destination folders:
$TargetFolders = 1..$n |ForEach-Object {
    mkdir "C:\TestDivide\sub$_"
}

# Find the .eml files sort by length, descending
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\TestExtract\0-1" -Recurse |Where-Object {'.eml' -contains $_.Extension} |Sort-Object Length -Descending

for($i = 0; $i -lt $Files.Count; $i++)
{
    # Move files into sub folders, using module $n to "rotate" target folder
    Move-Item $Files[$i].FullName -Destination $TargetFolders[$i % $n] 
}
```

And the zipping of the divided files like this

```
#Compress all the files based on folder structure

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\TestDivide\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
    $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
    $directoryName = $_.Name
    & "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip $directoryFullName\*
}


#Move the zip files to a specific directory

Get-childitem -path "C:\TestDivide" -Recurse -Filter "*.zip" | move-item -destination c:\Testdivide
```